# How can I bulk delete Django session variables?

Tags: django, session

I use sessions to store some API results as caches, though my session is db-based.

In particular, I use session keys like "product_{id}". When a user makes a bulk edit, I need to delete the cache so he can load API results. How can I bulk delete them?

I know I can manage sessions just like a model [out of view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views). Also, I can bulk edit with filter - [startswith](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters). like below.

```
q1 = Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="What")
```

However, the key looks like encoded as mentioned from the first link. How can I handle it?

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
s = Session.objects.get(pk='2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead')
s.expire_date
datetime.datetime(2005, 8, 20, 13, 35, 12)
```

Comment: In case you need this, you should make a model that links the user and the session model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `./manage.py clearsessions` to clear expired sessions. I didn't find a way to delete all of them though.

Comment: After the user finishes a bulk edit, the session may not be expired. Clearsessions can't clear the deprecated results shown to the user

Comment: you mean: https://pypi.org/project/django-clearcache/?